# Issue with count() in php

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have the following code block in my controller

```
$reportPostCountArray = $this->objUserModel->findDuplicateReportPost($payloadData['user_id'], $payloadData['post_id']);
var_dump($reportPostCountArray);

count($reportPostCountArray);
var_dump(is_array($reportPostCountArray));
```

and the output for the above code is  following:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#179 (1) {
    ["post_count"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
bool(true)
```

Please help me to correct why I am not getting the count value even though the return is an array with size 1.

Comment: Maybe because you are not printing count. Thats why?

Comment: `$cnt = count(...)`?

Comment: yes! what a stupid mistake it was! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what you want to do:

```
var_dump($count($reportPostCountArray));
```

You were not printing the count value with var_dump() but an array and the return value of is_array() which is indeed a boolean, in this case true.